# Requesting an external URL with Django

Tags: django, url

In the `save()` method on a model, I need to execute a request for an external URL, e.g.

```
def save(self):
    curl http://foo.dyndns.com/blah
```

I don't need it to return or handle any received data - just need to make the request (an Arudino board will receive and react to the request).

I'd prefer not to drop into `os.system()` to execute a curl statement - I'm thinking there must be some way to do this natively. Only I don't know how (Google results not helping much here).

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: You could use the signals provided by django, or use a custom save function with calling super on it.

Comment: Heh - this is one of those questions that's like a time capsule. 11 years ago I actually had to ask this on StackOverflow. Today, I would write it in requests with my eyes closed - funny to think it was ever a question in my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a request with [urllib2.urlopen](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen), but don't `.read` from the handler

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a work for requests: [Python HTTP for Humans.](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests)

Comment: `Requests` is awesome but I'm not sure if there's a practical benefit vs a one liner with the standard library.

Comment: Sounds good, but urllib2 is built in, and my needs are very simple here. But thanks.